# Cypher IF A AND NOT(B) in match

Tags: if-statement, neo4j, match, cypher

I want to write a cypher clause that says (I know this is not correct syntax, its just an example to show the general idea):

```
IF (S1)-->(B1{attr:TRUE})-->(G) AND NOT((S2)-->(B2{attr:FALSE})-->(G))
THEN stuff
```

So, if I have only the node `B1` with `attr=TRUE` I want the pattern to match. If I have `B1` with `attr=TRUE` and also `B2` with `attr=FALSE` I want the pattern **not** to match. In all other cases where *at least* `B1` with `attr=TRUE` is found, the mattern should match also.

But I cannot figure out how to implement this logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do that:

```
MATCH (S1)-->(B1{attr:TRUE})-->(G)
WHERE NOT ()-->({attr:FALSE})-->(G)
... stuff ...
```

Or, if `stuff` needs to use the `B2` nodes:

```
MATCH (S1)-->(B1{attr:TRUE})-->(G), (B2{attr:FALSE})
WHERE NOT ()-->(B2)-->(G)
... stuff ...
```

This should give you an idea of how to start. It all depends on what data your `stuff` needs to use, and how much you want to specify about the `S` and `B` nodes.